# Data from form being shown as gibberish in database after insert query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server, database

I have a simple form that allows a user to upload images and add a tags to images which I will use to search for the specific image.

I have a problem when run my SQL query: everything uploads to the database successfully but when I check the database - the images table the column I named `tags` shows up as gibberish and I cant seem to figure out why.

I echoed the values in the variable in the PHP code and I could see they are alright. Also I tried changing the char set and still no luck.

I am a beginner at PHP. Most of it I have learned by myself but I am an impasse at it.

hank you for your help and consideration in advanced

**this is my form**

```
<html>
<title>Upload Image </title>
<body>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="storeImage.php"  method="POST">

<table border=0 align=center bgcolor=black width=100%>
<tr><td colspan=2><h2>&nbsp</h2></td></tr>
</table>


<table border=0 align=center bgcolor=blue>
<tr><td colspan=2><h2>Upload Image</h2></td></tr>
<tr>
<td>Image Name</td><td><input type=text name="name"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Image Tags</td><td><input type=text name="tags"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Image</td><td><input type=file name="images"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td><td><input type=submit name="submit" value="Store Image"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**this is my code I used to store the images**

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$conn = mysql_connect ("localhost","root","vertrigo");
if(!$conn)
{
echo mysql_error();
}
$db = mysql_select_db("site_upload",$conn);
if(!$db)
{
echo mysql_error();
}

$name = $_POST['name'];
$tags = $_POST['tags'];
$images = addslashes (file_get_contents($_FILES['images']['tmp_name']));
$imagechk = getimagesize($_FILES['images']['tmp_name']);//to know about      image type etc

$image_type = $imagechk['mime'];

$q ="INSERT INTO images VALUES('','$name','$tags','$images','$image_type')";



$s =mysql_query($q,$conn);

if($s)
{

echo "Image stored successfully";
    echo"$tags";
}
else
{
echo mysql_error();
}


?>
```

**and my database structure**

```
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS site_upload DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 ;
USE site_upload ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table site_upload.images
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS site_upload.images (
    image_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(45) NULL,
    images LONGBLOB NOT NULL,
    tags LONGTEXT NOT NULL,
    image_type VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (image_id)
 )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you are inserting your image into your tag field and vice versa.  You declare your table to be "image_id, name, images, tag,..." but then when you insert you go image_id, name, tag, images,.."  A good standard is to always include the column names in your insert statement to avoid a situation just like this.

That being said, Technidev is also correct re: the other issues.

Comment: ghenghy your solution worked and i saw where i made my mistake and i appreciate your advice so too Technidev i was made aware of the outdated libraries that i am using i will address all those issues; by storing the path of the images in the database  instead and also using mysqli

Answer (score 0):

Besides the fact that your script is vulnerable to SQL injection, has no error handling, has no `<form>` open tag and makes use of outdated PHP libraries, it happens because you're storing the raw image in your database.

If you want to output the image, you have to output the content of the image only with the right headers which is probably image/jpeg or image/png in your case.

I assume that's what you meant?